# How to make screen scrollable vertically when part of the content overlaps

Tags: html, css

Imagine I have a div with fixed size like this:

```
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 200px; border: solid;">

    </div>
```

It's just a rectangle with solid border. Now when I zoom the screen, part of the rectangle is left out of screen (because it has fixed size). What I want is, when the part goes out of screen, there must appear a horizontal scroll bar, what to do? (Please don't suggest `overflow-x: scroll;` because it creates scrollbar even when it's not needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

This will only show scrollbar when it needs to.

Answer (score 1):

/* for both vertical and horizontal scrollbar */

/* they will display only when the rectangle part goes outside the screen */

```
overflow: auto;
```